# SD card memory sharing

Tags: ram, sd-card, chromebook, sharing, crouton

I am using Acer Chromebook 11 and its instaled with ubuntu 16.04 Xfce. I have a 64GB sd card, is there any way to share the same memory card in both OS. 
it is always a long step for me to use the auto-shared "Downloads" folder to exchange files, and doing it again and again whenever a change is made on any side

kindly help me...

Comment: yes, I installed ubuntu using crouton, both are running at the same time. kindly help me...

Comment: thank you for your response, I request others to kindly figure it out